# Domain Controller Upgrade 2019 to 2022

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2019, upgrade, windows-server-2022

I have 3 Domain controller in my environment Windows Server 2019 Standard.

1. Primary DC : On-prem (FSMO role)
2. Secondary DC : On-prem
3. Tertiary DC : Cloud

I want to upgrade my domain environment to windows server 2022.I tried to direct upgrade from mounted ISO. I didn't work due to  few BSOD messages.

[BSOD-SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLE][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpqKL.png

1. I have tried by removing all third party application, change CPU count and memory diagnostics

So I decided to install another DC and replace with secondary domain controller. But I need to keep it same as secondary domain controller **IP** and **Hostname**.What is best practice achieve this.

Comment: install a new device join them as controller. do the primary as last one and transfer the fsmo roles

Comment: Then use the same IP and host name. If you have a host that is crashing and you aren't pursuing the issue, turn it off and replace it.

Comment: any idea what are step to follow clean all the record of old domain-controller records. or just domain controller from AD